# Git log (--follow) not working to show history beyond renames

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I try to show the full history of a file in my git via gitlog.
The problem is that the parent folder of this file was renamed in the history, and  I like to see the full history.

The [git-log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow) says that the arguments `--follow` and `-M` show make git log following the renames.

I tried different combinations of the gitlog arguments like

`git log -M --oneline --all -- --follow newpath/my-file.php`

`git log -M --oneline --all -- newpath/my-file.php`
and even

`git rev-list --all -- newpath/my-file.php --objects --in-commit-order | git log --no-walk --oneline --stdin`

But whatever I try the history always ends at the commit where the parent folder of the file was renamed.

**I already can confirm that:**

- only the folder was renamed in the rename commit, the contents of the file are 100% unchanged, so git should simple discover that the file on the old path and the file on the new path are identicall and yust renamed.
- `git shot name-status` for the rename commit shows `R100    oldpath/my-file.php    newpath/my-file.php` (that confirms that contents of the file are 100% identical)
- The "old-half" and the "new-half" of the history seem to be correct, both include the rename-commt
- When I run `git log -M --oneline --all -- --follow newpath/my-file.php` the oldest commit is
  `0979744 renamed:    oldpath/ -> newpath/`
- When I run `git log -M --oneline --all -- --follow oldpath/my-file.php` the latest commit is
  `0979744 renamed:    oldpath/ -> newpath/`

So everything looks like my git successfull understands that the file in the new path and the file in the old path are renamed.
Can anybody tell me why the history still breaks on the rename commit even when I use the `-M` and `--follow` options ?

Comment: What if: `git log -M --oneline --all --follow -- newpath/my-file.php` ? `--` marks end of options.

Comment: I tested the change command for some files in my moved folder, it seems to be the solution to move `--follow` behind the `--`

Comment: Even it the follow renames seems to work now, when I add `--grep="rename" --invert-grep` to remove the "rename" commit, I get 0 results

Comment: Well, that's another issue. But maybe the solution is the same: you can't put any options after the `--` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454637/git-log-follow-not-working-to-show-histrory-beyond-renames#comment113972177_64454637), the `--follow` option must *precede* the stand-alone `--` that indicates the end of the options list.

> Even it the follow renames seems to work now, when I add `--grep="rename" --invert-grep` to remove the "rename" commit, I get 0 results

That makes sense (but is a bug of sorts),<sup>1</sup> because of the the *way* `--follow` works.  The issue here is that Git doesn't have any kind of *file history* at all.  All that Git has, is the set of commits that are in the repository.  *The commits are the history:*

- Each commit is numbered, by its big ugly hash ID, which is unique to that one particular commit.  No other commit—in *any* Git repository<sup>2</sup>—has that hash ID.
- Each commit has a full snapshot of every file.
- Each commit also stores the hash ID of a previous commit—or, for a merge commit, two or more previous commits.

So these numbers string commits together, backwards:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

The uppercase letters here stand in for the actual commit hash IDs, by which Git finds the commits.  Each commit has a "backwards-pointing arrow" coming out of it—the stored hash ID of the *previous* commit—so that if we could just remember the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, we could have Git work backwards through the chain.

A *branch name* just tells Git which commit is the *last* commit in that branch:

```
             I--J   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- feature2
```

Here, commit `J` is the *last* commit one of the feature branches and commit `L` is the *last* commit on another.  Note that commits up through `H` are on *both branches* (and quite likely also on the main or master branch as well).

The `git log` command simply works through the commits, one at a time, starting from whatever "last commit" you choose.  The default "last commit" is the one at the tip of whatever branch you have checked out right now.  This process works backwards: Git starts with the last commit and works backwards, one commit at a time.

The `-M` option to `git diff`, which is short for `--find-renames`, enables rename detection in `git diff`.  The `--follow` option to `git log` does the same for `git log`, but also takes the name of *one single file* to look for.  (Giving the `-M` option to `git log` makes it use the rename detector at each diff, but since it's not looking for *one specific* file, that just affects the `-p` or `--name-status` style of output.  With `--follow`, `git log` *is* looking for that one specific file, as we'll see in a moment.)

The rename detector works this way:

- You give Git two commits, *before* and *after* or *old* and *new* or, say, `F` and `G`.  (You *can* put the new commit on the left side, and the old one on the right, but `git log` itself always puts older on left, newer on right.)
- You have Git compare the snapshots in these two commits.
- Some files in those commits are 100% identical: they have the same name *and* the same content.  Git's internal storage system has de-duplicated these files and this makes it very easy for `git diff` or `git log` to decide that these files are *the same*, so it can skip right over them if appropriate.
- Other files have the same *names* but different *contents*.  Git assumes, by default, that if the two files have the same *name*—such as `path/to/file.ext`: note that the embedded slashes are just part of the file's name—they represent the "same file", even if the contents have changed.  So that file is modified, from the old / left-side commit to the new / right-side commit.  If you ask for `--name-status`, you'll get `M`, *modified*, as the status for that file name.
- Sometimes, the left-side commit has a file named, say, `fileL`, and the right-side commit doesn't have that file at all.  That file is *deleted*, apparently, in the change from old (left) to new (right).  With `--name-status` you would get `D` for the status.
- Sometimes, the right-side commit has a file named, say, `fileR`, and the left-side commit just doesn't.  That file is *newly added*, apparently, and with `--name-status` you would get `A` for the status.
- But what if `fileL` on the left and `fileR` on the right should be considered to be "the same file"?  That is, what if we *renamed* `fileL` to `fileR`?  This is where Git's rename detector comes in.  Given deleted/added pair like this, *maybe* the *content* of `fileL` is sufficiently close to, or exactly the same as, the *content* of `fileR`.  If:

  - you have turned on the rename detector, which will actually do this content-checking, and
  - the content-checking says "exactly the same" (very fast to know due to the de-duplication) or "sufficiently similar" (much slower, but enabled by the same rename-detector switch),

  then—and *only* then—Git will declare that `fileL` was *renamed* to become `fileR`.  The `--name-status` output will include `R`, the *similarity index* value, and the *two* file names, rather than the single file name that matches in both left and right side commits.

Now that you know how the rename detector works—and that it has to be *switched on*—you can see how `--follow` works.  Remember that with `git log`, you can give it a file name, and tell it *not* to show commits that *don't* modify that particular file.<sup>3</sup>  The result is that you only see commits that *do* modify that file: a subset of the set of all commits that `git log` visits.  So let's say you run `git log --follow -- newpath/my-file.php`:

- `git log` walks through history, one commit at a time, backwards, as usual.
- At each commit, it compares *this* commit (newer, on right) against its parent (older, on left).  Without `--follow` it would still do this, but just look to see if the file you *named* was *changed* (`M` status, from `git diff --name-status`) or *added* or *deleted* (`A`, `D`).<sup>4</sup>  But with `--follow`, it also looks for an `R` status.
- If the file *was* changed—has `M` or `A` or `D` status—`git log` *prints out* this commit, but if not, it just suppresses the printout.  With `--follow`, we add the `R` status and, if that happens, the two file names.  If the status *is* `R`, well, `git log` has been looking for `newpath/my-file.php` before.  But now it knows that, as of the *parent* commit, the file was called `oldpath/my-file.php`.  (Note, again, that there is no *folder* here.  The file's name is the whole string, including all the slashes.)

So, with `--follow`—which turns on the rename detector—`git log` can get a renamed status and therefore see that the file gets renamed.  It's also looking for *one specific file name*, in this case, `newpath/my-file.php`.  If it detects a rename, `git log` not only prints the commit, but also *changes the one name it is looking for*.  Now, instead of `newpath/my-file.php`, from the parent commit on backwards, it is looking for `oldpath/my-file.php`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `--follow` code itself is ... not very good; the whole implementation needs to be reworked, which would probably fix this better than the simpler hack I'm thinking of.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, some other Git repository *could* have a *different* commit that re-uses that hash ID, as long as you never introduce the two commits to each other.  In practice, you won't find one, though.

<sup>3</sup>The `--follow` option can only follow *one file name*.  Without `--follow`, you can give `git log` more than one name, or the name of a "directory" even though Git doesn't really store directories at all.  Without `--follow` the `git log` code operates on generic pathspecs.  *With* `--follow`, it only handles one file name.  That's a limitation imposed by the algorithm Git is using here.

<sup>4</sup>It could also have `T`, type-changed, and I *think* that would count.  The full set of status letters is `ABCDMRTUX` but `X` indicates a bug in Git, `U` can only occur during an unfinished merge, `B` can only occur with `git diff` with the `-B` option, and `C` and `R` can only occur with the `--find-copies` and `--find-renames` (`-C` and `-M`) options enabled.  Note that `git diff` may automatically enable `--find-renames` based on your `diff.renames` setting, but `git log` won't.

---

#### The bugs in `--follow`

This process, of removing some commits from the output display from `git log`, is called *History Simplification*.  There is a long section in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) that describes this, and it begins with this rather odd claim:

> Sometimes you are only interested in parts of the history, for example
> the commits modifying a particular <path>. But there are two parts of
> *History Simplification*, one part is selecting the commits and the other
> is how to do it, as there are various strategies to simplify the
> history.

What this weird phrasing—"one part is selecting the commits and the other is how to do it"—is trying to get at is that with history simplification enabled, `git log` sometimes doesn't even *walk* some commits.  In particular, consider a *merge commit*, where two strings-of-commits come together:

```
          C--...--K
         /         \
...--A--B           M--N--O   <-- branch
         \         /
          D--...--L
```

To show *all* commits, `git log` will have to walk commit `O`, then `N`, then `M`, then both `K` and `L` (in some order), then all the commits before `K` and all the commits before `L` going back to `C` and `D`, and then rejoin a single thread at commit `B` and keep going from there, backwards.

If we're not going to show *all* commits, though, maybe—just *maybe*—at commit `M`, we could just go back to *only commit `K` or only commit `L`* and ignore the other "side" of the merge entirely.  That will save a *lot* of work and time, and avoid showing you stuff that's irrelevant.  This is usually a really good thing.

For `--follow`, however, it's often a pretty bad thing.  This is one of `--follow`'s issues: sometimes Git will go down the "wrong leg" when doing this kind of simplification.  Adding `--full-history` avoids this, but we immediately stumble into another problem.  The `--follow` option has only *one file name*.  If we have a rename in one of the two legs of the commit, but not in the other, and `git log` goes down the rename leg first, it may look for the *wrong name* when it goes down the other leg.

If the file is renamed in *both* legs, so that it's renamed from `M` back to `K` *and* from `M` back to `L`, or if Git happens to go down the correct leg in the first place *and* you don't *care* about the other leg, everything works.  But it's something to be aware of.  (This is not the problem that's hitting you with `--grep`, or it would occur without `--grep`.)

I *think* the bug you are seeing is that `--grep` is firing off "too early", as it were. The `--grep` option works by eliminating, from `git log`'s output, any commit that has (`--invert-grep`) or lacks (`--grep` without `--invert-grep`) some particular text in its commit *message*.  Suppose, then, that the rename commit—the one that causes `git log --follow` to know to use the name `oldpath/my-file.php`—gets *skipped* by your `--grep` option.  Git won't *see* the `R` status, and won't know to change the name from `newpath/my-file.php` to `oldpath/my-file.php`.  So `git log --follow` will keep looking for the *new* path, and you'll get only those commits that both meet the grep criteria *and* modify a file with the new name.

This bug could be fixed by having `git log --follow` run the diff engine anyway, even if it's going to skip the commit for other reasons.  But more generally `--follow` needs a complete rewrite: it has a bunch of weird special case code threaded through the diff engine just to make this one case work.  It needs to handle multiple path names and/or pathspecs, and work with `--reverse` and other options.  It needs a way to stack old and new names onto commit paths, so that with `--full-history`, going down both legs of merges, it knows which path to be looking for.  Note that this has other implications: what if, going down both legs of a merge, there are *different renames?*  If there was a rename/rename conflict that someone fixed manually in the merge, how do we deal with that?

Comment: Wow, great bunch of informations.
I understand now whats the problem.
The big question is now: Is there a way to hide the "rename" commit from git log, but make the `--follow` option still check the rename actions in this commit ?

Comment: No. Note, however, that you can get the list of commit hash IDs you care about separately (with `git log --follow` with a format of `%H`), *remove* one specific commit that you don't want visited, then *view* those commits with `git log --no-walk --stdin` redirected to a file containing the remaining hash IDs.

Comment: I tried to do this with the `git ref-list` commandi n my question, but git ref has no `--follow` option. I think using git log twice with a grep between sounds like a good workarround.