# Is there a way to move git file history to another file?

Tags: git

I'm making changes in my repostiory.

So I have file `index.d.ts`, And I want to move all of its content to another file `file1.d.ts` and I want to move all of `index.d.ts` commits history to the new file.
But I still don't want to delete 'index.d.ts' from the repository.

I tried to use `git mv index.d.ts file1.d.ts` but once I recreate `index.d.ts` with the new content, then the history is automatically move back to `index.d.ts` and removed from `file1.d.ts`

Is there a way to move current `index.d.ts` file history to file `file1.d.ts` ?

Comment: did you commit the mv to file.d.ts before you re-created index.d.ts?

Comment: Probably not possible if you don't want to change file name...

Answer (score 2):

When you want to see the history of a file after it has been renamed, you can use

```
git log --follow <filename>
```

It will keep giving you the history of the file through the rename commits all the way back to when the file was first created with its original name.

So use

```
git mv index.d.ts file1.d.ts
```

commit the results, and then later when you want to see the history, use

```
git log --follow file1.d.ts
```

Ideally, make a commit with just the `git mv` operation, and then make a separate commit for changes you want to do in the file after renaming it. `--follow` can still find a rename if you make some changes to the file, but if you change it too much it might fail to recognize that it was a rename, and not an unrelated new file.

**EDIT** in [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72712205/3216427) they point out an important detail: if you want to have a different `index.d.ts` file back in your repo after having `git mv`'d it, add it back in as a separate commit from the `git mv`, otherwise you'll break the ability of `--follow` to detect the renaming operation. Details in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [joanis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72709350/1256452) for a practical solution: rename the file, commit, and then add a *later, separate commit* in which you add a new file that re-uses the old name.  This enables `git log --follow` to follow the rename.

#### What to understand about how and why this works

You asked about "moving history to another file", but Git doesn't *have* "file history" in the first place.  What Git has are *commits*.  The commits *are* the history.

Each commit, in Git, holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  (Each commit also holds some metadata, but for this answer we'll just concentrate on the snapshots.)  The files *in* these snapshots are compressed, Git-ified, and frozen for all time and—this is important—*have their content de-duplicated*.  The de-duplication means that if you have any pair of commits in a row—Git calls these "parent" and "child" commits, but for thinking about it for the moment, just think of them as "before" and "after", or "old" and "new"—and in the *old* commit there's some file that reads "I am a file", and in the *new* commit there's some file—with any name at all—that *also* reads "I am a file", these two files are *duplicates* of each other, and are *de-duplicated*.

Git can find a de-duplicated file with extreme ease.  Git can find *similar* files (files that are not quite the same, but are mostly the same) but it's much harder than finding files that match up because they were already de-duplicated.  Git's main *purpose* with this de-duplication is that when you made the new commit, you probably only changed one or two files, out of dozens, or hundreds, or millions, or whatever, in the old commit.  So *almost all files* in a new commit are duplicates of the old files in the old commit.  By de-duplicating the contents, Git saves lots of space: it only *really* has to save any *modified* file, even though both commits "contain" all the files.

Now, as I just said above, the history in a repository is nothing more or less than the *commits* in the repository.  When you run `git log`, Git finds the *current* commit—usually the latest commit on some branch, which you selected by running `git checkout mybranch` or `git switch mybranch`—and then works backwards, one commit at a time, showing you each commit's log message.  That's because the commits *are* the history: if we start at the *last* one and show its log message, then hop back one to its parent and show *that* log message, then hop back one and show *that* log message, then ... well, repeat until we run out of commits: we've now seen the history.<sup>1</sup>

Sometimes, though, we want to know: *In which commits did I **change** file F?*  So instead of just:

```
git log
```

we run:

```
git log -- F
```

The double hyphen here is required if `F` is *also* a branch name for instance, to tell `git log` that we mean *file* `F` and not *branch* `F`; when `F` isn't mis-interpreted, we can leave out the `--`, but it's a good idea to include it every time.

This *still* walks through all<sup>2</sup> the commits, backwards, one commit at a time.  But this time Git makes use of the "file is exactly the same - contents got de-duplicated" thing.  Let's say that in the *current* commit, file F exists and is exactly the same as it is in the previous (parent) commit.  Git can load up the two commits' snapshots, immediately see that the file was de-duplicated, and *not bother to print anything out* about the current commit.

Git then moves back one hop to the previous commit.  Git finds its parent, loads up the two snapshots, and checks to see if the file is the same (de-duplicated) or different (not-de-duplicated).  If it's the same, Git *doesn't mention this commit*.  If it's different, Git *does* mention this commit, in the usual way.

We then repeat, forever, one commit at a time, checking to see if this commit and the previous commit both have the same version of the file (or both omit the file entirely).  If so, the commit is *uninteresting* and Git doesn't print it.  If not—if the file has changed, or sprung into existence, or been deleted, due to *this* commit—then this commit is *interesting* and Git *does* print it.

The end result of this is that we "see" a "history of file F".  But there isn't a history of file F: there are just commits, and those are the history.  What we've seen instead of a "history of F" is "all history, except for commits where F didn't change".  Is that the same thing?  Well, maybe: enter `--follow`.

Suppose we're at some pair of commits <`old`, `new`>.  Git will extract the two snapshots and see if the file named F exists in both, or in neither.  Suppose further that F exists in `new` but *does not* exist in `old`.  Git can now—because of `--follow`—look for some file that *does* exist in `old` and *doesn't* exist in `new`.  Let's say there are five such files.  These are our *candidate files*.  We now check to see if any of these five files are "similar enough" to the copy that's in `new`.

This check goes really fast for "absolutely identical", so we have Git do that check first.  If any of the five files are 100% identical and hence got de-duplicated, why, the file whose name is oldF in `old` must have been *renamed* to F in `new`.  So:

- `git log` prints commit `new` because the file changed (it was going to do this anyway), *and*
- `git log --follow` *changes the name it is looking for*.  It's no longer looking for file F, it's now looking for oldF.

If the 100% identical thing doesn't work out, `git log` uses the slower, "is it close enough" match.  You can set the matching threshold: the default is to require at least a 50% match.  If more than one file meets the threshold, Git will take the highest matching file and call that the "old file" name.  If no file meets the threshold, Git will assume that file F is deleted, and continue looking for the name F to see if it gets re-created in earlier commits.

For all this to work, the *old file name* has to *vanish* between some pair of commits, and you have to start `git log --follow` with the *new* file name that *appears* in that same old/new commit-pair.  Committing a rename-only operation will guarantee that (a) this happens, and (b) the match is a 100% match and therefore goes fast.  So making a rename-the-file commit as a separate commit makes `git log --follow` work pretty well.

(There are flaws in `git log --follow`, though.  See footnote 2, and note that as currently implemented, `--follow` can only handle *one* file name.  You must know the *new* name: `--follow` does not work with `git log --reverse`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, we've seen the *reachable* commits, starting from the current commit and working backwards.  For (much) more on *reachability*—which is another key concept in Git—see [Think Like (a) Git](https://think-like-a-git.net/).

<sup>2</sup>This isn't quite true: `git log -- <path>` turns on what `git log` calls *History Simplification*.  This makes Git *drop* certain history paths.  When using `--follow` this is less of a loss than it might seem.  For (much) more on this, see, e.g., [git log does not return the history of a file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67595564/1256452), [Git log (--follow) not working to show history beyond renames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64454637/1256452), and other answers that mention history simplification.